# How do I compare inputs[0] and inputs[1] to see if they are similar?

Tags: python, arrays, list, arraylist, project

I am making this little python project were you input how many iterations (sets of two) you want to input and check if each pair is similar.

```
inputs = []
iterations = int(input())
loop_counter = 0
printNum = 0

while loop_counter<iterations*2:
    currentInput = input()
    inputs.append(currentInput)
    loop_counter += 1
    print(inputs[printNum])
    printNum+=1
```

So, I want something like this:

```
if(inputs[0] similar inputs[1]): #code here
```

Comment: only the words will be shifted or what? I mean in the example you've share in the comments of Aditi's answer, only the words were shifted. Did I get that right?

Comment: What does "similar" mean? Please explain in the body of your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by similar you want to check if they are equal
You an simply do it by:

```
if inputs[0]==inputs[1]:
    #your code
```

For the similarity quotient you can follow this:

```
set1 = set(inputs[0].split(' '))
set2 = set(inputs[1].split(' '))
if set1 == set2:
    #your code
```

To compare "ben bro" and "ben mate"

```
i1= inputs[0].split()
i2 = inputs[1].split()
for ii in i1:
    if ii in i2:
         print("test!")
```

Comment: The problem with that is that both of them need to be identical. For example, if inputs[0] == "mt bra" and inputs[1] == "bra mt" I want those two to compare and it should return similar.

Comment: Here when you split a string to list and convert them to string you'll get `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'` error!

Comment: Why do you have to convert it back to string? inputs[0] and inputs[1] has the original string

Comment: Aditi, I'm having an issue with your code. My code now: `inputs = []
iterations = int(input())
loop_counter = 0
printNum = 0


def check():
        set1 = set(inputs[0].split(' '))
        set2 = set(inputs[1].split(' '))
        if set1 == set2:
                print("test!")


while loop_counter<iterations*2:
 currentInput = input()
 inputs.append(currentInput)
 loop_counter += 1
 print(inputs[printNum])
 printNum+=1
 check()

def check2():
        if (loop_counter>=iterations*2):
                check()

`

Comment: It says that '1' is too far in the list. Or something like that.

Comment: As i can check you are calling check function even before inputs[1] has been given an input.

Comment: Okay, I "fixed" my code but it isn't working. `inputs = []
iterations = int(input())
loop_counter = 0
printNum = 0


def check():
        set1 = set(inputs[0].split(' '))
        set2 = set(inputs[1].split(' '))
        if set1 == set2:
                print("test!")

def check2():
        if (loop_counter>=iterations*2):
                check()


while loop_counter<iterations*2:
 currentInput = input()
 inputs.append(currentInput)
 loop_counter += 1
 print(inputs[printNum])
 printNum+=1
 check2()


`

Comment: is it showing some error? or there is some issue with the output?

Comment: No error. But, I inputed two same things at the 0 and 1 index and it doesn't print, "test!"

Comment: I dont see an issue wih the code. Can you share the inputs? or output screen? and just check by printing inputs in check function

Comment: there is one more issue with the code. It always check index 0 and 1 in input array. in iteration 2 it should compare inputs[3] and inputs[4]

Comment: Right, but you code means that it has to identical! I just tried it out!

Comment: So it can't be, "ben mate", "ben bro"

Comment: @Aditi, one question, what does the 'ii' represent in the for and if statements/loops? Thx

Comment: Okay so inputs[0].split() returns a list. For ii in list would mean individual element in the list. What i am doing is checking if any element in string 1 is present in any position in string 2. In your case ii would be ben and bro respectively in each iteration.

Comment: Got it! I understand. THX!

Answer (score 0):

You can basically sort your splitted string(split by space - default behaviour) and then compare them!

```
sorted(input[0].split())==sorted(input[1].split())
```

Example,

```
>>> input=['know it','it know']
>>> sorted(input[0].split())==sorted(input[1].split())
True
```

Happy Coding!